# move image down on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

usually when you scroll down on a page, the content moves up.

I need to create something similar to a window shade. Imagine a wall (your browser) with a window (a div) that has a pull-down shade (image) attached at the top. lets pretend that it's at top:-100px. When you pull the shade down (scroll down the div) the shade (image) 'reveals itself.' (goes from a top:-100px position, to top:0px position, to fill your window.

any help would be much appreciated!

this is a basic mockup that i've managed to piece together so far, from scouring similar questions here. it's obviously not working, and IT IS NOT RELAVENT TO WHAT I WANT TO DO AT ALL, but i was trying to make it relavent, but to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var $scrollingDiv = $("#aerobot");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
        "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"
    }, "slow");
});
</script>

<style>
body {
    height: 600px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#one {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:pink;
}
img {
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:blue;
    right:0;
    display:block;
}
#parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<div id="parent">
    <img title="yo" src="images/aerobot.png" id="aerobot" align="right" />
    <div id="one"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

any  help would be super duper appreciated!

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5f4r/)?

Comment: i believe that is what the user who commented below also had in mind. i elaborated a bit in my reply to tehm, but i'll add it to my OP for clarity. what i really want is something more like a window shade that scrolls down with the scroll bar. from a -px position at the top, to a 0px position so it fills the entire div frame.

Comment: Didn't really give it much time but let's try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5f4r/1/)

Comment: Here's a better version. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5f4r/2/)

Comment: Ahh yes! That second example is exactly what i was trying to do! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code. I think it is self-explanatory.

```
var img = document.getElementById("aerobot");
window.onscroll = function() {
    var bodyHeight  = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).height, 10);
    var scrollLimit = bodyHeight - window.innerHeight;
    var scrollTop   = document.body.scrollTop;
    var scrollPCT   = (scrollTop / (scrollLimit/100)) / 100;
    img.style.top   = bodyHeight * scrollPCT - img.offsetHeight + "px" ;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5f4r/10/)

Comment: thanks so much again! we managed to get it working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get a picture to stay where it was originally placed is to use css.

The way to do this would be with a `position: fixed;`

Comment: i don't want it to stay in one place though, i want it to move down as the page scrolls, like i stated in my OP. for example, imagine a wall with a window that has a pull-down shade. the wall is your browser window, the window is a div, and the shade is an image. when you pull down on the shade, it appears from teh top, to fill the window. that is what i'd like to do. an image within a div that moves down from a hidden position at the top to fill the div frame.

Comment: Okay, if you give everything else a fixed position and not give the image a fixed position, I believe it will appear like you want.